# How do I use a for loop to create a new 2D numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I asked a similar question before but it was worded badly. I figured some stuff out but not yet successful. I'm trying to create a new 2D array by calling a previous function. I want function_2 to do the same calculation as function_1 except in function_2 it's involving arrays rather than single values.

This is what I have:

```
import numpy as np 

def function_1(A,B):
    A = 10
    B = 2
    ans = A*B
    return ans


def function_2(C,D):

    C = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    D = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

    #here I create a zero array and include some other codes required

    for i in range(C): #each i are A values
        for j in range(D): #each j are B values
            array[i,j] = function_1(C,D)

    return array
print(array)
```

The above example gives me this:

```
[[25. 25. 25. 25. 25.]
 [25. 25. 25. 25. 25.]
 [25. 25. 25. 25. 25.]
 [25. 25. 25. 25. 25.]
 [25. 25. 25. 25. 25.]]
```

But I want it to take every value of C and D to do calculations and give me something like this:

```
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [2. 4. 6. 8. 10.]
 [3. 6. 9. 12. 15.]
 [4. 8. 12. 16. 20.]
 [5. 10. 15. 20. 25.]]
```

Thanks

Comment: `C[:, None] * D`

Comment: If `function_1` is more complicated and takes a long time for each pair of elements, you could use `np.vectorize`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
ans = []
for i in range(1,6):
    a =[]
    for j in range(1,6):
        a.append(i*j)

    ans.append(a)

ans = np.array(ans)
ans
```

using np.zeros

```
ans = np.zeros((5,5),dtype=np.int)
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(1,6):
        ans[i-1][j-1]=i*j
ans
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do it by first creating a zero array and also by calling the previous function? That's what I need to do as the function is more complicated than this example.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of errors in your code. Let's figure out.

1. You override the input value with defaults in the beginning of the functions:

```
def function_1(A, B):
    -> A = 10
    -> B = 2
    ...
```

Doesn't matter what the params will be passed to the function it will be const. But I don't understand why it `25` in your example and not `20`.

2. You cannot use `range` function with array. Please check [the reference](https://pynative.com/python-range-function/) of the function.

```
for i in range(C): #here
    for j in range(D): #here
        array[i, j] = function_1(C,D)
```

3. You passed arrays to `function_1`

```
 -> function_1(C, D)
```

I don't understand how did you get an array of `25.` with these errors. But fixed solution should be:

```py
import numpy as np


def function_1(A, B):
    ans = A * B
    return ans


def function_2(C, D):
    a = np.zeros((len(C), len(D)), dtype=int) # because you have to allocate matrix before use
    for idi, i in enumerate(C):
        for idj, j in enumerate(D):
            a[idi][idj] = function_1(i, j)

    return a


C = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
D = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array = function_2(C, D)
print(array)
```

And the better solution without functions

```py
import numpy as np

C = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
D = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

diag = np.diag(D)
rows = np.array([C, ] * 5)

print(np.dot(diag, rows))
```

Both solutions product:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 2  4  6  8 10]
 [ 3  6  9 12 15]
 [ 4  8 12 16 20]
 [ 5 10 15 20 25]]
```

Comment: `a[i, j]` is the preferred numpy indexing style.

Comment: @hpaulj removed